# How do I install the knife-ec2 plugin?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

OSX, 10.9.2:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
$ knife -v
Chef: 11.10.4
```

When I run:

```
$ knife ec2 server list
```

I get:

```
FATAL: Cannot find sub command for: 'ec2 server list'
The ec2 commands were moved to plugins in Chef 0.10
You can install the plugin with `(sudo) gem install knife-ec2
```

I have the gem installed:

```
sudo gem install knife-ec2
```

runs without error. And gem list shows that it is installed:

```
$ sudo gem list|grep knife-ec2 
knife-ec2 (0.8.0)
```

The gem appears to be correctly installed here:

```
ls /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/knife-ec2-0.8.0/
...
```

/usr/bin/knife on its own runs fine. Its quite likely it has something to do with where knife is looking for plugins, but what to do about it is unclear.

Answer (score 9):

I had this or a similar problem when I installed the chefdk after I'd already had chef/knife/knife-ec2 installed via gems (in an attempt to get vagrant-berkshelf working, if you're wondering).

What I found is that when installing the chefdk the embedded chef ruby is used by the knife binary in your path, instead of the system ruby, so you have to install your gems to the chef embedded ruby.

On OSX I did it like this:

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2
```

Edit: Looks like there's a chef command to do this already:

```
chef gem install knife-ec2
```

Comment: Cool, I found gem in following path, /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2

Comment: I had to $ sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2 to get it to install

Answer (score 3):

What's the output when you try running `gem install knife`? `gem` uses different paths when you run it with `sudo`

You can either run knife with sudo:

```
sudo knife ec2 server list
```

Or install gem as current user:

```
gem install knife-ec2
```

If the latter doesn't work, use RVM:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
rvm install 2.0.0p247
gem install knife-ec2
```

Comment: I have same problem and tried both sudo and without sudo for both gem and knife and still get same error. gem without sudo doesn't install plugin:


    ~/workspace/chef-repo/bin: (master)$ gem install knife-ec2
    Fetching: knife-ec2-0.8.0.gem (100%)
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the      /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Answer (score 1):

You are installing things into your system ruby (which is ill-advised). You need to use `sudo` before your `knife` command in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is tricky... 
Reason:
 You have 2 GEM binaries in your system. One by "rubygems in /bin/gem" and another by chef in "/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem"

Knife makes use of the gem binary in the chef installation.

Solution:
So you should have the plugins installed as 
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-ec2
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install

Enjoy :)...